# Java-Setting a tiimeout function when receiving a UDP packet java

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, timeoutexception

Im trying to send a UDP packet and then wait for a response back from the server for 2 seconds. If my socket does not receive a packet back from the server in this time, then I will have to send the same packet back again. I want the program to stop sending packets after it has sent 5 and then declare that the server is down.

Here is what I have, but I keep getting the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out

```
    clientSock.send(UDP_Packet);
    int count=0;
    while(count <5){
        try{
            clientSock.recieve(incomingPacket);
            clientSock.setSoTimeout(2000);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            clientSock.send(UDP_Packet);
            count++;
            if(count>=5){
            System.out.println("Server is Down");
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here or how to implement it?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to set the timeout *before* doing the receive, not afterwards, but the main issue is that you're catching the wrong exception. You should be catching `SocketTimeoutException`.